# 2 wire smart thermostat nest but no RC or RH

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, nest

I just got the new 2020 model nest and i was going to do the 24v transformer suggestion in other thread but these new models do not have RC or RH on them.  they only have Y,G,R,W,C,O/B.

Will the transformer not work or can i use another connection?

Comment: What do the instructions call for?

Comment: @jack you have to be careful on the thermostat colors because the furnace control board may have not been hooked up to standards , I gave a “friend” free advice once and ended up in court after he blew up a 700$ control board, it cost me 1/2 a day in court and his friendship but the wiring has to match the control not just colors. And yes he lost. Never try to sue someone for free advice because you can win all of what you paid.

Comment: which other thread?

Comment: @EdBeal  I read you loud and clear. That's why I've stayed away from  giving any advice on those newfangled thermostats. I'll stick with the round Honeywell ones .. lol

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring both at the thermostat *and* the furnace/air-handler ends please?

Answer (score 1):

The basic colors are Red =24v
White = heat
Yellow= cool
Green = fan
I have seen many different wiring ideas so it is best to verify how the existing one is wired or check at the control board and match that  common blue but I have also seen it as clear snd orange.

Comment: thanks and sorry for the lack of knowledge.  we just moved into the house 10 days ago and our first time with oil heating and old dial mercury thermostat.  there are only 2 wires going down to the furnace red and white.  i found many videos that showed how to add an external c wire by buying a 24v transformer (honeywell) and connecting one to C and the other to RH or RC and then plugging into the wall.  unfortunately the new models of the NEST dont have RC or RH

Comment: So basil has when red 24v is connected to white that is the call for heat. I primarily work with gas and propane the oil units I have worked with we were removing but I remember them having an electric pump ig